# Как исправить Bad request при отправки POST запроса?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

помогите разобраться!
Использую технологии: Spring, thymeleaf.

Есть форма с таким полем

```
<form th:action="@{/signUp}" th:object="${customer}"  method="post">
<input type="date" class="form-control" th:field="*{birthDate}" id="formBirthDay" placeholder="Birth day"></form>
```

При отправке формы получаю `Bed request` именно в тех случаях, когда это полу не пустое!

В  контроллере обрабатываю так:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signUp", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void regCustomer(@ModelAttribute Customer customer, SearchPassportForm searchPassportForm) {
    Customer cus = customer;
    logger.debug("SIGH-UP login customer " +  cus.toStringLogin());
    logger.debug("SIGH-UP login searchPassportForm " +  searchPassportForm.toString());
}
```

Помогите разобраться!

Comment: Если это Spring, Вы доступ к контроллеру по указанному адресу разрешили в настройках security?

Comment: Spring security ещу нет

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в конвентировании Date в LocalDate